# dynamodb - scan items by value inside array

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm doing a table scan. This table has an array as one of its fields, the "apps" field (apps is not a key of any kind). I want to select all rows, whose apps array contains a certain value "MyApp". I tried something of that kind, but my syntax is incorrect:

```
    ComparisonOperator = "#apps CONTAINS :v",
    ExpressionAttributeNames = {
        '#apps': 'apps'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues = {
        ":v": "MyApp"
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [documentation about Condition Expressions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html#ConditionExpressionReference.Functions) clearly states that the appropiate syntax is:

```
contains(#apps, :v)
```

The correct request would be:

```
FilterExpression: "contains(#apps, :v)",
ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#apps": "apps" },
ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":v": "MyApp" }
```